# Can I test my Dutch Google Action on locally on my device?

Tags: actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

I recently started working with Google Actions and Alexa Skill. 
The Google Assistant now supports the Dutch language on Android.
I can't seem to get my Dutch skill working on my Google home (alpha version)

Is this not possible yet or am I just doing something wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you still having this problem Mathias?

Comment: Yes @lukedavis, I talked to a Google engineer and he confirmed that at this time it's not possible to test skills in the Dutch language.